# Where to write dom manipulation after render? Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to update the dom accordingly to the url of the page, after the page has loaded.

Essentially in render: I am fetching data through an api, mapping this data to different buttons.

Dom manipulation I would like to do: Click the button related to the url, after the component has rendered. Basically if url = "/topicA" -> click button related to topicA.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) - what are you trying to achieve by having buttons be pressed based on the URL? Could you not trigger code based on the URL directly? Might a [router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/) better serve your needs? Tell us the problem you're trying to solve, not just what you're trying to do to solve it - the answers you get will be better that way :)

Comment: You should be able to use basic javascript to click the button in `componentDidMount` which is called after the component has rendered for the first time. As @JoeClay writes above you probably should not be taking this approach however.

Answer (score 0):

Use onload. The script will have to be on /topicA or the event will have to fire from the /topicA page. If not you can also use The localStorage Object to set button click to true or false if your redirecting to another page and use a conditional statement to fire call.

`<body onload="script();">`
or
`document.onload = function() {}`
or 
`window.onload = function() {}`